# Why is my PHP code passed in source to the client?

Tags: php

I'have just started to learn PHP, I'm using a free host to test my code but nothing happens and also my php code passed in source of page, does it show that server don't interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that shows that the server isn't interpreting it properly. The user should never receive PHP code, just the html/javascript/whatever that your PHP script outputs.

As for why this is happening, here are a few basic things to check:

- Your PHP code should begin with the `<?php` tag and end with the `?>` tag (the ending tag isn't strictly necessary, but any code you put after it won't be interpreted).
- The document's name should end with `.php` (not always necessary, but some server setups may require it).
- If you haven't checked already, make sure that the host you're using supports PHP in the first place.

Comment: @csstd It should start with the `<?php` tag. The most probable issue is that your host server isn't interpreting the PHP as such.

Comment: That's how it should begin. I edited my answer so it's less ambiguous.

Comment: thank you very much but changing the file name extension to php, it worked

Answer (score 1):

> Is php code passed in source to the client?

No.

Your PHP interpreter isn't being invoked.